# Type = submit not working in the form of bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

```
    <form class="form-asd" role="form">
     <h2>REGISTER</h2>
       <hr />
           EmailAddress:

         <input class="form-control" type="text" id="email" required/>
           <br />
           Password:
         <input class="form-control" type="password" id="Password" required />
           User Type
         <input style="width: 2.2em;height:1.3em" id="ContributorRdb" type="radio" name="choose" value="Contributor" required/>Contributor
         <input style="width: 2.2em;height:1.3em"  id="CategoryRdb" type="radio" name="choose" required/>
            <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="Select" disabled="disabled">
                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">type</option>
                <option value="one">one</option>
                    <option value="two">two</option>
                <option value="three">three</option>
                <option value="four">four</option>

            </select>
            <br/        
          <input  class="btn btn-lg btn-sucess"  id="Register" value="Sign up"/>

</form>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#Register').click(function () {
      alert("this is submitted");

   });
})

</script>
```

This above form works well without tag `type= submit` but when i modify the button to `input  class="btn btn-lg btn-sucess"  id="Register" value="Sign up" type="submit"` this form stops working so is there any way to use `type ="submit"` in this input tag.

Comment: `This above form works well without tag` What do you mean? Does it submit or show the alert?

Comment: What do you mean by *stops working*?

Comment: You not even mention what is the input type is ... This is not proper way... As you mention when you use submit, you must specify the right POST url to submit it

Answer (score 3):

I can imagine that the form doesn't work.

### Form attributes

Wrong: `<form class="form-asd" role="form">`

This should contain action and method.

Good: `<form class="form-asd" role="form" action="" method="post">`

### Submit button

Wrong: `<input  class="btn btn-lg btn-sucess" id="Register" value="Sign up"/>`

Should contain the type

Good: `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-sucess" id="Register" value="Sign up"/>`

### jQuery (not sure if you even include the library)

Wrong: `$('#Register').click(function () {`

Never asume that users always click the button (you can also use the `enter` key)

Good: `$('form').submit(function () {` (I would use a class or id in the form tag)

### jQuery 2

You don't prevent the default action, so your form will be submitted always.

You can add something like `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();` in the jQuery callback.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just submit the form, if that is what are you trying to attain. You can do this inside your document ready function like..

```
$('.form-asd).submit();
```

Or if this is the only form in your document then you can target the form using the form element selector like

```
$('form').submit();
```

Hope it helps :=)

Answer (score 0):

you can do a following change to the code to make it work.

```
<input  class="btn btn-lg btn-sucess"  id="Register" value="Sign up"/>
```

to

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-sucess"  id="Register" value="Sign up"/>
```

but definitely you should use the best practices suggested in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set action for the form <`form class="form-asd" role="form" action='youraction'>` and you can call `document.forms[0].submit()` in javascript, It will submit form.
 Hope this help!